# Turning sublayers on/off in QGIS2Web Leaflet export

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

For some simple maps, I need to turn sublayer on and off. Like in the example (a) and (b) with **Leaflet/Qgis2Web**.

[image: example map]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 methods that I know:

Use JavaScript and make a custom control, or check plugins to see if one fits.

Bring A and B in as separate layers by setting a filter in your JavaScript.

In QGIS, under the layer settings, provide a feature filter, using the query builder. Copy the layer twice in QGIS, use a separate feature filter for each layer, then run QGIS2WEB again.